# Error not showing on submit when setup to show error scenario

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a plugin. I have a simple form setup to display on the front end of the website. When you hit submit, it should show a validation error. As that is the scenario i setup. But no matter what I do I can not get it to show the error.

I made a similar plugin using this method and it works fine but is displayed in the admin dashboard and not the front end.

Here is my code, when you hit submit it should show an error message. Do you know why its not showing?

```
 <?php
      if (count(\Wbg\Base\Error::$errors)) {
        foreach(\Wbg\Base\Error::$errors as $error) {
          ?>
            <ul>
              <li>$error</li>
            </ul>
          <?php
        }
      }
    ?>

  <form action="" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="action" value="customer_send_request">
   <input type="hidden" name="_nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce('send-request'); ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="title" value="<?php echo time(); ?>">
   <input type="text" name="link" placeholder="Link to files" required>
   <button type="submit" name="submit">Send</button>
  </form>

 <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
         if (wp_verify_nonce($_POST['_nonce'], 'send-request')) {
         // dosomething...
         } else {
          \Wbg\Base\Error::setErrors('Invalid link');
         }
        }
     ?>
```

Comment: Does it display `$error` instead of the actual error?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Tom Udding 

It does not display anything. It displays the html wrapper <ul> and <li> tags but does not output the error or $error anywhere.

Comment: From what I can see it you aren't actually outputting the error (there isn't an `echo` or something like it). And (maybe it is like this because you copy/pasted your code here) you second PHP block does not have an opening/closing tag.

Comment: if (count(\Wbg\Base\Error::$errors)) {
        foreach(\Wbg\Base\Error::$errors as $error) {
          echo "<li>$error</li>";
        }
      }

Is what i just updated it to and it still is not outputting anything.

Comment: I am missing the php tags in the example only. I updated it in the example

Comment: Is the first code-block above the second code-block? If so, it will never display an error because the first block is executed before the second block (unless output buffering is enabled).

Comment: Thanks so much @Tom Udding. That was the problem indeed!

Feel free to post as a solution to the question. Thanks for your help!